# Flask serving static folder with CORS

Tags: python, flask, cors, static-files

In my frontend app I'm trying to access a file I'm serving in a static folder but I'm getting an issue with CORS. The issue I'm seeing is

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/static_folder/apple.xml' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My backend Flask app has the following set

`app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static_folder', static_folder="static_folder")`

It seems that I need to add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to my responses when returning the files. Does Flask have a global way to set this?

I've tried using `flask_cors` but haven't been successful with

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static_folder', static_folder="static_folder")
CORS(app)
```

I was able to get something similar working with the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` by setting the CORS headers as

```
def end_headers (self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)
```

But I'd like to use flask to accomplish this rather than starting a simple http server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after cors(app) add these lines:

```py
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    return response
```

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same issue.

Comment: your error is for No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' so you should add this line too: response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

Comment: I tried adding `response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` in addition to what you had above but no success. I tried to curl the static file and it seems the headers aren't getting applied properly

Comment: This is supposed to add all to origins, change CORS(app) to this CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins":"*"}})

Comment: and erase response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

Comment: Thanks! Looks like setting resources was successful in combination with the static folder and response headers got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if using the [flask-cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, you should be able to blanket your static requests:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

# Initialize
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/static/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Good luck!